# CNN architecture the same but getting different results

Tags: machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I have a CNN that saves the bottleneck features of the training and test data with the VGG16 architecture, then uploads the features to my custom fully connected layers to classify the images.

```
#create data augmentations for training set; helps reduce overfitting and find more features
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255,
                        shear_range = 0.2,
                        zoom_range = 0.2,
                        horizontal_flip=True)

#use ImageDataGenerator to upload validation images; data augmentation not necessary for 
validating process
val_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

#load VGG16 model, pretrained on imagenet database
model = applications.VGG16(include_top=False, weights='imagenet')

#generator to load images into NN
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        train_dir,
        target_size=(img_width, img_height),
        batch_size=batch_size,
        class_mode=None,
        shuffle=False)

#total number of images used for training data
num_train = len(train_generator.filenames)

#save features to numpy array file so features do not overload memory
bottleneck_features_train = model.predict_generator(train_generator, num_train // batch_size)

val_generator = val_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        val_dir,
        target_size=(img_width, img_height),
        batch_size=batch_size,
        class_mode=None,
        shuffle=False)

num_val = len(val_generator.filenames)

bottleneck_features_validation = model.predict_generator(val_generator, num_val // batch_size)`



#used to retrieve the labels of the images
label_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

#generators can create class labels for each image in either 
train_label_generator = label_datagen.flow_from_directory(  
    train_dir,  
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),  
    batch_size=batch_size,  
    class_mode=None,  
    shuffle=False)  

#total number of images used for training data
num_train = len(train_label_generator.filenames)

#load features from VGG16 and pair each image with corresponding label (0 for normal, 1 for pneumonia)
#train_data = np.load('xray/bottleneck_features_train.npy')
#get the class labels generated by train_label_generator 
train_labels = train_label_generator.classes

val_label_generator = label_datagen.flow_from_directory(  
    val_dir,  
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),  
    batch_size=batch_size,  
    class_mode=None,  
    shuffle=False)

num_val = len(val_label_generator.filenames)

#val_data = np.load('xray/bottleneck_features_validation.npy')
val_labels = val_label_generator.classes

#create fully connected layers, replacing the ones cut off from the VGG16 model
model = Sequential()
#converts model's expected input dimensions to same shape as bottleneck feature arrays 
model.add(Flatten(input_shape=bottleneck_features_train.shape[1:]))
#ignores a fraction of input neurons so they do not become co-dependent on each other; helps prevent overfitting
model.add(Dropout(0.7))
#normal fully-connected layer with relu activation. Replaces all negative inputs with 0 and does not fire neuron,
#creating a lighetr network
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.7))
#output layer to classify 0 or 1
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

#compile model and specify which optimizer and loss function to use
#optimizer used to update the weights to optimal values; adam optimizer maintains seperate learning rates
#for each weight and updates accordingly

#cross-entropy function measures the ability of model to correctly classify 0 or 1
model.compile(optimizer=optimizers.Adam(lr=0.0007), loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

#used to stop training if NN shows no improvement for 5 epochs
early_stop = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', min_delta=0.01, patience=5, verbose=1)

#checks each epoch as it runs and saves the weight file from the model with the lowest validation loss
checkpointer = ModelCheckpoint(filepath=top_model_weights_dir, verbose=1, save_best_only=True)

#fit the model to the data
history = model.fit(bottleneck_features_train, train_labels,
        epochs=epochs,
        batch_size=batch_size,
        callbacks = [early_stop, checkpointer],
        verbose=2,
        validation_data=(bottleneck_features_validation, val_labels))`
```

After calling train_top_model(), the CNN gets an 86% accuracy after around 10 epochs.

However, when I try implementing this architecture in by building the fully connected layers directly on top of the VGG16 layers, The network gets stuck at a val_acc of 0.5000 and basically does not train. Are there any issues with the code?

```
epochs = 10
batch_size = 20

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255,
                        shear_range = 0.2,
                        zoom_range = 0.2,
                        horizontal_flip=True)

val_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        train_dir,
        target_size=(img_width, img_height),
        batch_size=batch_size,
        class_mode='binary',
        shuffle=False)

num_train = len(train_generator.filenames)

val_generator = val_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        val_dir,
        target_size=(img_width, img_height),
        batch_size=batch_size,
        class_mode='binary',
        shuffle=False)

num_val = len(val_generator.filenames)`

base_model = applications.VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(img_width, 
img_height, 3))

x = base_model.output
x = Flatten()(x)
x = Dropout(0.7)(x)
x = Dense(128, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dropout(0.7)(x)
predictions = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x)


model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=predictions)

for layer in model.layers[:19]:
layer.trainable = False

checkpointer = ModelCheckpoint(filepath=top_model_weights_dir, verbose=1, save_best_only=True)

model.compile(optimizer=optimizers.Adam(lr=0.0007), loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics= 
['accuracy'])

history = model.fit_generator(train_generator, 
                          steps_per_epoch=(num_train//batch_size), 
                          validation_data=val_generator,
                          validation_steps=(num_val//batch_size),
                          callbacks=[checkpointer], 
                          verbose=1,
                          epochs=epochs)
```

Comment: These two training procedures are not the same. But the thing that confuses me is the fact that the first model achieved better accuracy. I expect otherwise. BTW, have you tried a lower or higher learning rate in second approach? Could you please try this and report back the result.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that in the second approach, you have not frozen the VGG16 layers. In other words, you are training the whole network. Whereas in the first approach you are just training the weights of your fully connected layers. 
Use something like this:

```
for layer in base_model.layers[:end_layer]:
        layer.trainable = False
```

where end_layer is the last layer you are importing.

Comment: No. It has already been done: `for layer in model.layers[:19]: layer.trainable = False`.